# In ffmpeg, can I specify time in frames rather than seconds?

Tags: animation, audio, video, ffmpeg

I am programatically extracting multiple audio clips from single video files using ffmpeg.

My input data (start and end points) are specified in frames rather than seconds, and the audio clip will be used by a frame-centric user (an animator). So, I'd prefer to work in frames throughout.

In addition, the framerate is 30fps, which means I'd be working in steps of 0.033333 seconds, and I'm not sure it's reasonable to expect ffmpeg to trim correctly given such values.

Is it possible to specify a frame number instead of an [ffmpeg time duration](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#time-duration-syntax) for [start point (`-ss`) and duration (`-t`)](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#Main-options)? Or are there frame-centric ffmpeg commands that I've missed?

Comment: hmmm, https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pydub might suit my requirements better here (but still not frame-centric)

Answer (score 1):

Audio frame or sample numbers don't correspond to video frame numbers, and I don't see a way to specify audio trim points by referencing video frame indices. Nevertheless, see this [answer](https://superuser.com/q/1021053/114058) for more details.

Comment: linked answer looks helpful, even if it's to confirm a "no", thanks